Convergence of $\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}$ as $n\to \infty$ using Mathematica or otherwise

Using Mathematica or otherwise, I need to find the convergence or divergence
of$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}$$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ and $n!$ is the factorial of $n$.

We have $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}=H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}$$ where $H^{(r)}_{n}$ is the generalized harmonic number.
So we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$$
I have observed the behavior of the fractional part using Wolfram Alpha. The plot shows that $\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$ oscillates between $y=0$ and $y=1$. So my gut feeling is that the sequence $\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$ is not convergent.
I tried the following code on Wolfram Cloud as well:
 a // ClearAll;
 a[n_] /; MemberQ[Stack[], Limit] := FractionalPart[n!*HarmonicNumber[n!,5]];
 SumConvergence[a[n], n]

But I am getting output as:
 SumConvergence[a[n],n] 

Again I tried
 SumConvergence[FractionalPart[n!*HarmonicNumber[n!,5]], k, Method->"IntegralTest"]

But I am getting the output as
 SumConvergence[FractionalPart[n! HarmonicNumber[n!,5]],k,Method->IntegralTest] 

Please give a code for the convergence or divergence of the sequence.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

I'd recommend asking this question on the math SE because it does not seem suited for Mathematica analysis.

Let's change n! to nfact.
sum = Sum[1/k^(3/2), {k, nfac}]
(* Out[66]= HarmonicNumber[nfac, 3/2] *)

InputForm[ser = Series[nfac*sum, {nfac, Infinity, 1}]]
(* Out[70]//InputForm=
SeriesData[nfac, Infinity, {Zeta[3/2], -2, 0, 1/2}, -2, 3, 2] *)

So the product is Zeta[3/2]*n! -2*Sqrt[n!]+... where the elided part is all terms going to zero. Notice that Sqrt[n!] is an algebraic number for all integer n. If zeta(3/2) is transcendental (unknown) then there can be no limit to the fractional part (it will give, as @roman noted, a sequence uniformly distributed mod 1). If it's algebraic then I've no idea what can be shown, other than it "probably" still won't have a limit.

$(+1)$. Thanks. Please let me know if anything more comes up.

If $\zeta(3/2)$ is algebraic, I'll start a podcast about paint drying.

@GregHurst I for one would be delighted to learn how to use the zeta function to dry paint. (It's not just about the application...)

Let's define some functions to evaluate these numbers at high accuracy:
$MaxExtraPrecision = ∞;
f[n_Integer?Positive] := FractionalPart[n! HarmonicNumber[n!, 3/2]]
g[n_Integer?Positive] := g[n] = N[f[n], 100] // N

Show the sequence:
DiscretePlot[g[n], {n, 1000}]


The numbers seem to be pretty random and spread uniformly over $[0,1]$:
Histogram[Array[g, 1000], {0, 1, 1/10}]


A Kolmogorov–Smirnov test supports this observation:
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[Array[g, 1000], UniformDistribution[]]
(*    0.24534    *)

If it is true that the sequence $f_n$ is quasi-random and uniform on $[0,1]$, then it won't converge.

Thanks. ($+1$). How to show that the sequence $f_n$ is quasi-random and uniform on $[0,1]$?

No idea – that's why I suggested going to the math stackexchange. The Kolmogorov–Smirnov test is merely an indication that it looks quasi-random.

What do you mean by quasi- random and uniform

I mean a low-discrepancy sequence. Quasi-random, for practical purposes. No easy pattern can be seen.

Thanks. Please let me know if anything more comes up.
